# Undefined reference to 'main' when using ifort/icc

Tags: c, gcc, fortran, symbols, icc

I am trying to compile a code that is written in Fortran and then linked through the C compiler. The problem comes when I try the Intel compilers, ifort + icc. If I do the same with GNU compilers, gfortran + gcc, it works.

Bellow we can see their outputs.

**ICC, *not* working:**

> ifort -c  -o fonts/pgpack.o -g -fno-automatic -fPIC fonts/pgpack.f
>   ifort: command line warning #10006: ignoring unknown option '-fno-automatic'
>   icc -o pgpack  fonts/pgpack.o   -O2  -L/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080/compiler/lib/intel64 -L/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080/ipp/../compiler/lib/intel64 -L/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080/ipp/lib/intel64 -L/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080/compiler/lib/intel64 -L/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080/mkl/lib/intel64 -L/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080/tbb/lib/intel64/gcc4.4 -L/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080/compiler/lib/intel64 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/ -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../lib64 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../lib64/ -L/lib/../lib64 -L/lib/../lib64/ -L/usr/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/../lib64/ -L/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080/compiler/lib/intel64/ -L/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080/ipp/../compiler/lib/intel64/ -L/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080/ipp/lib/intel64/ -L/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080/mkl/lib/intel64/ -L/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080/tbb/lib/intel64/gcc4.4/ -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../ -L/lib64 -L/lib/ -L/usr/lib64 -L/usr/lib -L/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080/compiler/lib/intel64 -L/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080/ipp/../compiler/lib/intel64 -L/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080/ipp/lib/intel64 -L/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080/compiler/lib/intel64 -L/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080/mkl/lib/intel64 -L/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080/tbb/lib/intel64/gcc4.4 -L/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080/compiler/lib/intel64 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/ -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../lib64 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../lib64/ -L/lib/../lib64 -L/lib/../lib64/ -L/usr/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/../lib64/ -L/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080/compiler/lib/intel64/ -L/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080/ipp/../compiler/lib/intel64/ -L/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080/ipp/lib/intel64/ -L/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080/mkl/lib/intel64/ -L/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080/tbb/lib/intel64/gcc4.4/ -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../ -L/lib64 -L/lib/ -L/usr/lib64 -L/usr/lib -lifport -lifcore -limf -lsvml -lm -lipgo -lirc -lpthread -lsvml -lc -lgcc -lgcc_s -lirc_s -ldl -lc
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../lib64/crt1.o: In function '_start':
>   (.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'

*Note*: it is strange to me that icc is linking against gcc libraries (/usr/lib/gcc/...). Is this normal/right?

**GCC, working:**

> gfortran -c  -o fonts/pgpack.o -O2 -Wall -fno-second-underscore -g  -fno-automatic -fPIC fonts/pgpack.f
>   Warning: Nonconforming tab character in column 6 of line 15
>   Warning: Nonconforming tab character in column 6 of line 16
>   Warning: Nonconforming tab character in column 6 of line 17
>   Warning: Nonconforming tab character in column 2 of line 19
>   Warning: Nonconforming tab character in column 2 of line 20
>   Warning: Nonconforming tab character in column 2 of line 21
>   Warning: Nonconforming tab character in column 2 of line 24
>   Warning: Nonconforming tab character in column 2 of line 25
>   gcc -o pgpack  fonts/pgpack.o   -O2  -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../lib64 -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/../lib64 -L/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080/compiler/lib/intel64 -L/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080/ipp/../compiler/lib/intel64 -L/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080/ipp/lib/intel64 -L/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080/compiler/lib/intel64 -L/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080/mkl/lib/intel64 -L/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080/tbb/lib/intel64/gcc4.4 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../.. -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../lib64 -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/../lib64 -L/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080/compiler/lib/intel64 -L/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080/ipp/../compiler/lib/intel64 -L/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080/ipp/lib/intel64 -L/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080/compiler/lib/intel64 -L/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080/mkl/lib/intel64 -L/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080/tbb/lib/intel64/gcc4.4 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../.. -lgfortranbegin -lgfortran -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc
>   : pgpack

I notice that some libraries being linked changed (e.g, libgfortranbegin), but that is automatically added/changed by the make system.

I already tried solutions offered by other posts, for similar errors, like use the flag (ifort)`-nofor-main` and (icc)`-nostartfiles`, but it keeps failing.

What am I missing?
Thanks.

Comment: I'm not a Fortran coder, but the problem is that ifort does not export a symbol spelled 'main' when compiling *fonts/pgpack.f*. Try running `nm fonts/pgpack.o` and see if there's something similar to 'main' in there (you could paste the output). It could be a C vs. C++ issue for example, if icc uses different symbol naming conventions for those. In C++ this would be solved with `extern "C" { <declarations> }`.

Comment: You really should link with whatever compiles the main program.

Comment: to start, both methods are displaying warnings.  Warnings need to be corrected, not ignored!  The different compilers have different parameters, so duplicating the parameters is not the right way.  for gcc, there should also be -Wextra and -pedantic and probably something like: -std=c99

Comment: looking at the list of parameters to the 'icc' it is obvious (due to numerous repetitions of the paths to the libraries and the paths to libraries that the compiler 'should' already know about, and the '../../../' kinds of sequences in the library paths, that the OP needs to read the documentation on the compilers.

Comment: the call to ifort should include '-warn all' so all compiler warnings are enabled.

Comment: regarding the warning about '-fno-automatic',  I suspect what you actually wanted was: '-auto-scalar'

Comment: @user3629249 I doubt the warnings will fix the main problem. And I do not recommend to use `-pedantic` for gfortran.

Comment: @user3629249, the path format you are complaining about (and the number of paths) very likely arises from automation, perhaps an Autoconf `configure` script.  It is not inherently an indication of misuse or even uninformed use.  It *is* suspicious, however, that the icc version appears to point to both Intel and GNU library directories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `icc` case, none of the modules you are linking provides a function `main()` to be the entry point of the program.  That `gcc` nevertheless links the program successfully is probably due in part to the inclusion of `-lgfortranbegin` in the link.  That will provide a standard (for `gfortran`) `main()` function that sets up the Fortran environment before handing off control to a differently-named routine corresponding to the `PROGRAM` subunit defined in `pgpack.f`.

It is likely possible to link an `ifort`-compiled object file into a complete program via `icc`, but apparently you need an `ifort`-specific starting point routine, and none of the libraries you specified provides one.  In any event, it is likely wrong that you are including GCC libraries in the `icc` link.  I presume that your build system is identifying and including those, but it is incorrect in doing so.

In any event, it is surpassingly strange that you are linking with `gcc` / `icc` when you have only a single object file derived from a Fortran source.  You should be linking with the Fortran linker driver, which in both cases is the same as the Fortran compiler driver (`gfortran` / `ifort`).  In that case you probably do not need *any* of the `-L` or `-l` options you are currently specifying.

Even if you were linking in some C routines, too, generally you should use the linker driver for the language in which the main routine is written.  There are caveats, and it gets more complicated if you roll some other languages into the mix (e.g. C++), but your particular case looks very simple.

Comment: The `libgfortranbegin` is a legacy backward compatibility stuff. It is not used in recent versions of GCC.

Comment: @VladimirF, perhaps so, but libgfortranbegin is still relevant to GCC 4.4.7, which the OP appears to be using.  I happen to be able to verify that directly.